# Virtual reality app perfromance in android mobile remains same even is showd a lot performance improvement in Editor play in unity3d

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, simplygon

I am building an app in android for Google cardboard Virtual Reality(VR) in Unity3d engine.Since for VR performance matter a lot for best experience.
I used [Simplygon](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10144) (From Assert store) to combine all textures in my app.

Stats are shown below unfortunately there is no improvement in performance when running on mobile but there is a improvement in editor.

Am I missing something ,What may be the reason for this?

Are they any options to reduce performance in mobile build as well?
**Profile window stats of Unity Editor:**

*Before using Simplygon*: ( FPS is around 60 )
[image]

*After using Simplygon* : (Crossed 250 FPS), But Tris and Verts count Increased a lot.

[image]

**Profile window stats of Android mobile**:

*Before optimization*:

[image]

*After Optimization:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> *Are they any options to reduce performance in mobile build as well?*

Presumably you meant are there any performance improvements you can make?

You also said that you benchmarked against the editor. This isn't a good idea - for starters - what renderer for unity are you using? OpenGL is more similar for Android than DirectX.

You need to measure more. Then measure more specifically (unity has some good performance logging helpers) before you can make useful changes..

Comment: Yeah I am using OpenGL2. It preforms better than OpenGL3 is seems. Could you mention performance logging helpers, it will help a lot. Thanks :)

Comment: You can use Profiler.BeginSample() and EndSample() pair around sections of code. Even more sophisticated is that you can have a static helper script to record any custom field to the profile log. It would also be wise to not have this log in the application path causing Unity to get involved in opening the file!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are optimizing, differences in hardware can have a huge impact on which optimization are impactful, and which don't make any difference.  Since the android architecture is so different from a PC, it becomes a total crap-shoot as to whether other stuff that helped on the PC will also help on the mobile device.  To make matters worse, things that help on one mobile device might not help on another one, say, from a different manufacturer.

In your case, the rise in polygon count was, apparently, simply more painful that then texture benefit, for your particular phone.  Although, to be honest, there could be some simple settings to fix, too - someone else might have suggestions there.

Like others have said, various performance probes can help you find your bottlenecks.